# Request an Apple Pay Payment Session

Tags: applepay, applepay-web

We develop website and need to add  apple pay, in specific point apple pay JS class receive validation URL ... Which will send to back-end to validate and request apple pay session, in this part of steps we need to declare all domains which displays Apple pay button and verify them in developer account, but what about server domain which will use to request apple pay session also need to add it to verified domain in developer account ?

Apple pay official documentation is not clear